# Jquery - detect the click outside of input

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input id="ok" /> 

$('.hor-minimalist-a').on('blur','#ok',function(){

});
```

with this code above, i can handle events which fire If i *leave* the input field.

How can I detect if someone clicks outside of inputfield *without* coming to input. I mean the user never came to this input field before, so there was no focus at all.

```
$('.hor-minimalist-a').on('?','#ok',function(){
  ?
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ( e.target.id != 'ok' ) {
        // you clicked something else
    }
});
```

That would capture any click except on the input, but why would you need it ?

To capture only clicks on `.hor-minimalist-a` and not the entire document, just replace `document` with that selector in the code above.

Comment: i need it, because i have an edit icon where if user clicks a new input field shows up. on blur, the input fields shuts down, but i suspect also, that after hitting edit-icon, the user can decide not to edit. so in this case, on any click outside, the inputfield should shut down

Comment: Then you should set up an example, and ask for that specifically, as that would probably require setting a flag wnen the edit icon is clicked, and then check for the next click etc. The best thing would probably be to just focus the input when the edit icon is clicked, and capture the blur event and then check the value.

Comment: oh man, this is the best option (setting the input to focus). i will go for it :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$('.hor-minimalist-a').on('click',':not(#ok)',function(){
```

That'll register click events within `.hor-minimalist-a` but outside the `input #ok`

Answer (score 1):

There is a jquery plugin for that:
http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-outside-events/examples/clickoutside/